# Xamarin IOS - MediaURL path issue from UIImagePickerController

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am able to capture a new video using UIImagePickerController without issue.

However, I am not able to successfully use a video selected from the library. I believe the issue is the path provided in mediaURL and that I am not using it correctly.

The code below is a snippet from my FinishedPickingMedia handler, where the app tries to copy the video to the app's temp directory, then show the video preview. I get an error that the path is invalid at the step of trying to copy the video. The error is: Could not find a part of the path "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/971EF812-BB6C-4C2A-92CF-5BC7DA8D0CC8/GoingUp.iOS.app/file:/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/971EF812-BB6C-4C2A-92CF-5BC7DA8D0CC8/GoingUp.iOS.app/file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/2879B6F6-A91E-42A5-ADEB-5D23336F391A/tmp/trim.0F2C4B16-EE5B-4048-BE30-5EE7B0A7064D.MOV".

```
var vid = new FileResult(e.MediaUrl.ToString());
//I have tried to use CreatFileURL thinking that would help; it doesn't.
var vidURL = NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(e.MediaUrl.ToString(), null);

//This fails with the error above:                 
System.IO.File.Copy(vidURL.ToString(), System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), vid.FileName));
                
final_vid = new FileResult(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), vid.FileName));
```

I have also tried using e.MediaUrl directly, same issue.

I don't really have a need to store the video in the app's temp directory; but I do so because I believe the mediaURL becomes invalid quickly. If that's not correct, I am open to a different approach.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: After the user selects their video, I present them a video preview, which they can then confirm and the app uploads to the video to Amazon S3. This process works without issue when the user creates a new video using the camera, but I am getting the above mentioned error when I try to use a selected video that already exists in their album.

Comment: Could you post the value of `vidURL.ToString()` and `vid.FileName` here ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's far harder than it should be, huh!